# I can't use method upper python

Tags: python

I am new to python, I was following a course taking every detail cuz I know that missing any detail in the beginning will lead to big problems but I failed to avoid them anyway, here is the thing I am using python 3.6 and pyCharm as the editor, the instructor uses method method called 'upper("string")' to convert a string letters into capital it caused a problem with him at the beginning but he used the intention action and imported the following library (or what ever it is called in python)

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import upper
```

I tried to search for the solution but all solutions didn't work for me, I installed django and virtualenvwrapper using command lines:

1.pip install django
  2.pip install virtualenvwrapper-win

,then restarted pyCharm, but the problem still exists.

any solution I will appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean with *can't use*? What happens if you use it?

Comment: This is the wrong upper. You need str.upper.

Comment: I mean it does not exist, it gives me unresolved reference

Comment: he used it without the string after adding this library

Comment: I mean without str.upper()

Comment: I tried it it worked as you said but what about his way or is that other thing, If you wish i can take a screen shot of what he did

Comment: Why not just `def upper(s): return s.upper()` if you want to call `upper()` as a function rather than a method? You shouldn't need any imports.

Comment: Perhaps post a code snippet of what you're running and the error it's giving you as well.

Comment: I will try it, just a sec

Comment: I believe the problem lies within the way pycharm handles packages.

Comment: Holy hell, do not install `django` *simply for an upper-casing function*. That's crazy.

Comment: @JohnColeman or better yet, `upper = str.upper`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or `str.upper(string_obj)`.

Comment: @ChristianDean sure, of course, I would just use `my_string.upper()` like a normal Python person.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga lol, yep. I'm not exactly sure why the OP needs `str.upper` to be a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, installing django for using upper is like killing a fly with a tank. Django is a framework for web development.
I think you are looking for

```
"Hello World".upper()
```

That would give you "HELLO WORLD".

That because thats a method of the string class, not a python function. (I'm not quite sure if upper exist as a python built-in function)

Comment: You can always use `upper = str.upper` and call it like `upper("Hello World")`

Comment: thank u this helped but I really want to understand what did he do

Comment: he imported:
from django.template.defaultfilters import upper

Comment: then he used upper as a function normally

Comment: @MohammadElsayed it is hard to say why in the world the instructor is using `upper` from `django.template.defaultfilters` Indeed, it makes little sense unless it is a class specifically about `django`. Note, in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L293) the functio is essentially `def upper(my_string): return my_string.upper()`

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's extreme overkill to install a web framework to uppercase a string. Simply use `str.upper`:

```
>>> string = 'abc'
>>> string.upper()
'ABC'
>>>
```

However, if you don't want to call `.upper` as a method (for some reason?), you can call the `str.upper` method directly and pass in a string object:

```
>>> string = 'abc'
>>> str.upper(string)
'ABC'
>>>
```

The [`upper` method defined in `django.template.defaultfilters`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L293) seems to simply be a [wrapper around the `str.upper` method that converts anything passed in to a string object automatically](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L35):

```
@register.filter(is_safe=False)
@stringfilter
def upper(value):
    """Convert a string into all uppercase."""
    return value.upper()
```

Comment: thank you you gave me more understanding about django as a web development framework

Comment: Glad I could help out, @MohammadElsayed :-)